# Removing the address collection from the Spree order process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a Spree 2.1.4 store where I am attempting to remove the address collection step in the order process. Currently I have `/app/models/spree/remove_address_decorator.rb`:

```
Spree::CheckoutController.class_eval do
  def before_payment; end
end

Spree::Order.class_eval do
  remove_checkout_step :address
end
```

I am getting an error: `IndexError in Spree::OrdersController#update`, `:address is an invalid name`. I overrode `before_payment` based on [this bug](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/3142).

I also tried:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  checkout_flow do
    go_to_state :delivery
    go_to_state :complete
   end
end
```

I get the same error.